Eigenvectors of matrices and solutions of (finite dimensional) Schroedinger equation
I am trying to understand certain statement in physical literature (a reference is given below). My question is a finite dimensional version of what is really necessary.
Let $A,B$ be Hermitian $n\times n$ matrices. Let
$\chi\colon \mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$
be an infinitely smooth function such that
\begin{eqnarray}
\chi(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
         0&\mbox{ if }& t<0,\\
         1&\mbox{ if }&t>1.
         \end{array}\right.
\end{eqnarray}
For a paramater $\lambda>0$ let $\psi_\lambda\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}^n$ be a solution of (a finite dimensional version of) the Schrodinger equation
$$i\frac{\partial\psi_\lambda}{\partial t}=(A+\chi\left(\frac{t}{\lambda}\right)B)\psi_\lambda.$$
Note that for $t<0$ the equation becomes
$i\frac{\partial\psi_\lambda}{\partial t}=A\psi_\lambda$,
and for $t\geq \lambda$ it becomes
$i\frac{\partial\psi_\lambda}{\partial t}=(A+B)\psi_\lambda.$
(Thus $B$ is interaction Hamiltonian which is switched on adiabatically.)
Assume in addition that $\psi_\lambda(0)$ is an eigenvector of $A$.
QUESTION. Is it true that there exist complex numbers $c_\lambda$ with absolute value 1 such that $\lim_{\lambda\to +\infty}c_\lambda \psi_\lambda(\lambda)$ exists and is an eigenvector of $A+B$.
Remark. The question was motivated by an attempt to understand the first few lines in $\S 16.3$ in the book "The Quantum Theory of Fields", vol. II, By S. Weinberg.

This is the adiabatic theorem. You need a gap condition, where the eigenvalue remains separated from other eigenvalues during the time evolution, to prevent the eigenstate of $A$ from evolving into a superposition of eigenstates of $A+B$. The finite-dimensional setting is of particular importance in quantum computing (adiabatic quantum computing). For a treatment of the adiabatic theorem in that context, see Bounds for the adiabatic approximation with applications to quantum computation (2006).
